# Write a variable in live expressions stm32cubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Is there a possibility to write a value in the live expressions tab of the stm32cubeIDE? I found this feature very useful in the IAR EW. When I change a value in the live expressions the debugging session and the system stops working.

I have stm32cubeIDE v1.12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not implemented yet. I however found out that there is a workaround to this issue. After the version 1.12.0 you can see the address in the live expressions of the memory where it is saved. You can open the memory window and pause the program that the values of the memory are displayed. Here you can change the value that you want and afterwards continue the debugging session.
I suggested this feature to stm as it would be nice to have it, even with the workaround.